# Reduce font size and keep label position in bar chart using PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am preparing a bar chart in PGF and it is a pleasure to work with. The only problem is that I have trouble reducing the font size used to indicate the value associated to each bar. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %small,
    ybar,%=8pt, % configures ‘bar shift’
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={index},
    symbolic x coords={1982, 1990, 1999, 2006},
    %xtick=data,
    %tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    nodes near coords,
    %every node near coord/.style={font=\footnotesize},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1982, 1.78) (1990, 1.71) (1999, 1.68) (2006, 1.62)};
\addplot coordinates {(1982,  1.70) (1990, 1.62) (1999, 1.59) (2006, 1.64)};
\addplot coordinates {(1982, 2.04) (1990, 1.96) (1999, 1.95) (2006, 1.91)};
\legend{USA, Netherlands, {(West-)Germany}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Plot resulting from MWE.]

This gives a wonderful plot. Probem is, the bar labels are too large and overlap. I tried changing this using `every node near coord/.style={font=\footnotesize},`. However, then the labels all appear above each other and are not above the corresponding bars anymore. How can I keep them at their right places? Is this a bug?

Comment: You can try `every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},`

Comment: I still gotta learn a lot about TikZ... That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I switch my comment to an answer.

You are using `every node near coord/.style={font=\tiny},`. In this case all predefined settings will be lost. `pgfkeys` has a special handler to add an extra option to a defined style named `append style`. Based on this information you can use `every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %small,
    ybar,%=8pt, % configures ‘bar shift’
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={index},
    symbolic x coords={1982, 1990, 1999, 2006},
    %xtick=data,
    %tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
   nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1982, 1.78) (1990, 1.71) (1999, 1.68) (2006, 1.62)};
\addplot coordinates {(1982,  1.70) (1990, 1.62) (1999, 1.59) (2006, 1.64)};
\addplot coordinates {(1982, 2.04) (1990, 1.96) (1999, 1.95) (2006, 1.91)};
\legend{USA, Netherlands, {(West-)Germany}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And if you're using ConTeXt, use the `\switchtobodyfont` command:

`every node near coord/.style={font={\switchtobodyfont[8pt]}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you posted an immediately-compilable full example, rather than just a code fragment.