# Change font size inside pgfplots stacked bar figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fontsize

I have with great effort succeded in building a satisfactory stacked bar using pgfplots.
I'm trying to finetune it and I think, because the first bars are quite small, it would be great that my labels appear smaller. However, I haven't found how to do just that in the (super extensive but quite clear) pgfplots documentation.

To make myself clearer (English is not my first language), I would like the numbers inside of the bars to be smaller so they aren't overlapping each other.

I'm including a screenshot and a section of my code. Many thanks! :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float} % figer tableaux et graphs
\usepackage{xcolor} %Gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{graphicx} %Gestion des images

\usepackage{pgf, tikz} %pour tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots} % boites à moustaches
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.9} % histogrammes et boites à moustaches
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics} 

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Données nationales : Répartition des élèves dans les groupes de niveau selon le domaine évalué en septembre 2018 (en pourcentage)}
    \vspace*{5mm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      bar width=15pt,
      nodes near coords,
      enlargelimits=0.06,
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      symbolic y coords={Reconnaître les différentes écri..., Comprendre des mots à l'oral, Connaître le nom des lettres et..., Manipuler des phonèmes, Manipuler des syllabes, Comparer des suites de lettres, Comprendre des phrases à l'oral, Comprendre des textes à l'oral},
      ytick=data,
      y tick label style={anchor=east},
      ]
      \addplot+ [xbar] coordinates {(3.2,Comprendre des textes à l'oral) (3.5,Comprendre des phrases à l'oral)  (5.5,Comparer des suites de lettres) (6.2,Manipuler des syllabes) (5.4,Manipuler des phonèmes) (6.8,Connaître le nom des lettres et...) (5.7,Comprendre des mots à l'oral) (14.3,Reconnaître les différentes écri...)};
      \addplot+ [xbar] coordinates {(6.7,Comprendre des textes à l'oral) (14.4,Comprendre des phrases à l'oral) (13.1,Comparer des suites de lettres) (12.8,Manipuler des syllabes) (16.5,Manipuler des phonèmes) (16.2,Connaître le nom des lettres et...) (20.9,Comprendre des mots à l'oral) (24.6,Reconnaître les différentes écri...)};
      \addplot+ [xbar] coordinates {(90.1,Comprendre des textes à l'oral) (82.1,Comprendre des phrases à l'oral) (81.4,Comparer des suites de lettres) (81,Manipuler des syllabes) (78.1,Manipuler des phonèmes) (77,Connaître le nom des lettres et...) (73.4,Comprendre des mots à l'oral) (61.1,Reconnaître les différentes écri...)};
      \legend{En difficulté, Fragile, Satisfaisant}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Visualization of attached code]

Comment: Do you mean something in the lines of this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51095/reduce-font-size-and-keep-label-position-in-bar-chart-using-pgf-tikz

Comment: @Jes ooooo, yes, it's exactly that! Sorry, I lack of vocabulary because I had no idea those were called "nodes", hence not finding the solution by myself.

Many thanks ! :)

Comment: No problems, glad to help!

Comment: @Jes Yes ! Sorry I don't know how to mark a comment as suitable answer, but if you want to answer the question I can mark it resolved. Have a great day ! :)

Comment: No, don't worry, the comment is duplicated because I flagged the question to be a duplicate. I did not know it would be posted as a comment! Have a lovely day too.